# WoT Flashcards Connect to MyJSON

Tags: json

I am currently working on an app for pleasure that will allow me return from an api, information on a  character from the WoT book series that matches the input given. I am testing, to make sure that I still know how to write an api but apparently not. I've tried to mimic the syntax of other apis (the pokemon api) but I am still not able to actually write it so that the input triggers the content to be delivered to my page..

I have written the following api, at api.MyJson.com, and it has accepted the input. I want the user input to be the id for right now ( ex. 1, 2, etc) and when I am able to return 'undefined', so it's not js innerhtml line.. 
I've also left little console.logs that seem to be fired all the way through the connection and have even tested on other apis successfully with the exact code (file even)

The API syntax is :

```
 {
   "characters": [
     {
       "id": 1,
       "gender": "male",
       "name": "Rand al'Thor",
       "archtype": "Taveren",
          "bio": "Rand al'Thor born in the year 978 NE on the slopes of"
      },
     {
  "id": 2,
  "gender": "male",
  "name": "Perrin Aybara",
  "archetype": "Taveren",
  "bio": " He is a strong ta'veren, a wolfbrother, and has exceptional skills in manipulating Tel'aran'rhiod. He is also husband to the Lady Faile ni Bashere t'Aybara, first in succession to the vacant throne of Saldaea. "
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "gender": "male",
  "name": "Matrim Cauthon",
  "archetype": "Taveren",
  "bio": " Matrim Cauthon, born in the year 978 NE and usually called 'Mat', he is one of the main characters of the series. He is the Marshal-General of the Band of the Red Hand, and the husband of the Empress of the Seanchan empire, as well as one of the greatest generals the world has ever seen. "
}
     ]
 }
```

when I search the api link,https://api.myjson.com/bins/zjg2k/, I can't find my data but when I include any of the id's at the end of the link (ex. https://api.myjson.com/bins/zjg2k/2 ), it can't be reached ( in contrast to the pokemon api.. )

I can note, however, that I have a console.log that does repeat, where I would only expect to see it once, right under the  'onreadystatechange = function() command.. 
Here is the actual code:

```
    window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("swSubmit").addEventListener('click', getSW);
 } 

  function getSW(){
        console.log("get SW! ");
    let swId = document.getElementById('swId').value;
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            console.log("ready state is changing!! CHAAAANGINNNNGG!!");

            if(xhttp.readyState==4 && xhttp.status==200){
                let sw = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                setValues(sw); 
            }

        }
        xhttp.open("GET",'https://api.myjson.com/bins/6fcl8' + swId);

            console.log("getting here?"); 
        xhttp.send();
 }
  function setValues(sw){
    document.getElementById("WoTName").innerHTML = sw.name;
    // document.getElementById("WoT").innerHTML = sw.gender;


  }
```

tbh, I'm a bigger WoT fan than coder and I have a beautiful front end page for this and I really want to make this work before the amazon prime series hits! But I need some fundamental help to make this scalable! thank you!

Comment: by the way, the element I'm sending the api to is,

<h2 id="WoTName"> </h2>

Comment: I've also tried using " 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/6fcl8'/character' + swId " in the GET request.